# How to use a regex with Awk to extract the substring between parentheses?

Tags: regex, indexing, awk, substring

In the following Bash command line, I am able to obtain the index for the substring, when the substring is between double quotes.

```
text='123ABCabc((XYZabc((((((abc123(((123'

echo $text | awk '{ print index($0, "((((a" )}'  # 20 is the result.
```

However, in my application, I will not know what character will be where the "a" is in this example. Therefore, I thought I could replace the "a" with a regex that accepted any character other than "(". I thought that /[^(}/ would be what I needed. However, I have been unable to get the Awk index command to work with any form of regex in place of the "((((a" in the example.

**UPDATE:** It was pointed out by William Pursell that the index operation does not accept a regex as the second operand.

Ultimately, what I was trying to accomplish was to extract the substring that was located after four or more "(", followed by one or more ")".  Dennis Williamson provided the solution with the following code:

```
echo 'dksjfkdj(((((((I-WANT-THIS-SUBSTRING)askdjflsdjf' | 
mawk '{match($0,/\(\(\(\([^()]*\)/); s = substr($0,RSTART, RLENGTH); gsub(/[()]/, "", s); print s}'
```

Thanks to all for their help!

Comment: The reason your final example gives "1" is: the expression `/[a-z]/` is equivalent to `$0 ~ /[a-z]/` which is equivalent to `1`, and the index of the string `1` in your input is 1.  `index` does not take a regular expression for the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match four or more open-parentheses in order to find the start of yet another substring within the match, you actually have to calculate the value.

```
# Use GNU AWK to index the character after the end of a substring.
echo "$text" |
awk --re-interval 'match( $0, /\({4,}/ ) { print RSTART + RLENGTH }'
```

This should give you the correct starting index of the character following the sequence of parentheses, which in this case is 24.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a variation that works with MAWK, instead of GNU AWK? The --re-interval is not an option in MAWK.

Comment: awk: not an option: --re-interval  is what I get when I run the above command.

Answer (score 2):

To get the position of the first non-open-parenthesis after a sequence of them:

```
$ echo "$text" | awk '{ print match($0, /\(\(\(\(([^(])/, arr); print arr[1, "start"]}'
20
24
```

This show the position of the substring "((([^(]" (20) and the position of the character after the parentheses (24).

The ability to do this with `match()` is a GNU (`gawk`) extension.

**Edit:**

```
echo 'dksjfkdj(((((((I-WANT-THIS-SUBSTRING)askdjflsdjf' | 
    mawk '{match($0,/\(\(\(\([^()]*\)/); s = substr($0,RSTART, RLENGTH); gsub(/[()]/, "", s); print s}'
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a variation that works with MAWK, instead of GNU AWK? Going further, what I also want is to extract the substring that lies between the last of four or more "(" and the next ")". Example: dksjfkdj(((((((I-WANT-THIS-SUBSTRING)askdjflsdjf.

Comment: @GaryH.: Please see my edited answer. Please edit your question to include this new information (which you should have included initially).

Comment: Your solution is perfect for what my goal was. My original question related to the index operation, and the answer to that question was that the index operation did not accept a regex for the second operand. Later, as I received suggested alternatives, I began to move toward a different approach, which culminated in your solution.  Should I still change the original question as you suggest?

Comment: @GaryH.: Yes, or post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You want `match` instead of index.  And you need to escape the `(`s.  For example:

```
echo $text | awk '{ print match($0, /\(\(\(\([^(]/) }'
```

Note that this does not give the index of the character after the string `((((`, but the index of the first `(`.